# compare a single input to 2 table columns

Tags: sql, yii

does anyone here experienced using criteria->compare for comparing a single input to 2 separate table columns via the relations in models?

here's my relationship declaration:

```
    'class' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BaseEiEquipItem', 'iar_no'),
    'classSi' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BaseSiReceivedItem','iar_no'),
```

now i want to compare my input if it is existing in either of these 2 tables

```
    if(!empty($_GET['BaseIar']['description'])){
        $this->description= $_GET['BaseIar']['description'];
        $criteria->with = array('class','classSi');//this will serve as join
        $criteria->compare('class.description,classSi.description', $this->description, true ); // true is equivalence of like %%
    }
    else{
        $this->description='';
        $criteria->with = array('class','classSi' );//this will serve as join
        $criteria->compare('class.description,classSi.description', $this->description, true ); // true is equivalence of like %%
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
$criteria->compare('class.description', $this->description, true);
$criteria->compare('classSi.description', $this->description, true, 'OR');
```

Answer (score 0):

why u r repeating the same code time and again try to use ternary operator
try this

```
$this->description = (!empty($_GET['BaseIar']['description'])) ? $_GET['BaseIar']['description'] : '';
$criteria->with = array(
                    'class' => array(
                      'condition' => "class.description LIKE :desc"
                      'params' => array(":desc" => "%{$this->description}%")
                    ),
                    'classSi' => array(
                      'condition' => "classSi.description LIKE :desc"
                      'params' => array(":desc" => "%{$this->description}%")
                    ));
```